# How to get the billing address before process payment in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have to get the checkout token from a payment server before processsing payment. How to get the billing address for user account and guest account. Is it possible to get the billing address info. I am doing a cusotm payment  gateway plugin.

```
public function curlrequest(){
    $data = array( 
        "page_id" => $this->page_id,                        
        "Currency" => get_woocommerce_currency(),
        "amount" => '100',
        "datetime_utc" => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        "transaction_type" => "authorize",
        "billing_address"=>('first_name'=>'','lastname'=>'') // need to pass here
    );                                                                    
    $data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                  

    $ch = curl_init('https://xxxxxxxxxx/paymentgateway');                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',  
        'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("$this->api_username".':'."$this->api_password"),                                                                              
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
    );  

    return respone token;                 
}

public function payment_fields() {
    echo '<input id="checkout_token" name="checkout_token" type="hidden" value="'.$this->curlrequest().'" />';
    //other cc common fields
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `WC_Customer` methods like:

```
$billing_first_name = WC()->customer->get_billing_first_name();
$billing_last_name  = WC()->customer->get_billing_last_name();

$billing_address_1  = WC()->customer->get_billing_address_1();
$billing_address_2  = WC()->customer->get_billing_address_2();
$billing_postcode   = WC()->customer->get_billing_postcode();
$billing_city       = WC()->customer->get_billing_city();
$billing_state      = WC()->customer->get_billing_state();
$billing_country    = WC()->customer->get_billing_country();
```

Or the `WC_Session` Customer data that can be accessed using the following:

```
$customer_data      = WC()->session->get('customer');

$billing_first_name = $customer_data['first_name'];
$billing_last_name  = $customer_data['last_name'];

$billing_address_1  = $customer_data['address_1'];
$billing_address_2  = $customer_data['address_2'];
$billing_postcode   = $customer_data['postcode'];
$billing_city       = $customer_data['city'];
$billing_state      = $customer_data['state'];
$billing_country    = $customer_data['country'];
```